# Use foreach inside php array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

Is there a way I can put this foreach inside the array?
For now I have this ugly solution..

```
$date = [];
$query = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT * FROM stock_list WHERE SLI_type = :type ORDER BY SLI_date DESC LIMIT 11');
$query -> execute(array(':type' => $_GET['aksjegraf']));
foreach ($query as $row) {
    array_push($last_ten_prices, $row['SLI_price']);
    array_push($date, $row['SLI_date']);
}

$dataPoints = array(
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[10], "label" => date('H:i', $date[10])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[9], "label" => date('H:i', $date[9])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[8], "label" => date('H:i', $date[8])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[7], "label" => date('H:i', $date[7])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[6], "label" => date('H:i', $date[6])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[5], "label" => date('H:i', $date[5])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[4], "label" => date('H:i', $date[4])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[3], "label" => date('H:i', $date[3])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[2], "label" => date('H:i', $date[2])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[1], "label" => date('H:i', $date[1])),
    array("y" => $last_ten_prices[0], "label" => date('H:i', $date[0])),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, like this:

```
foreach ($query as $row)
  $dataPoints[] = ["y" => $row['SLI_price'], "label" => date('H:i', $row['SLI_date'])];
```

If you want it in reverse order use [`array_reverse($dataPoints)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), or change the order in the query.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence Cherone!

Comment: np, sidenote: dont use ` * ` if you don't need every column, you could also do `SELECT SLI_price as y, DATE_FORMAT(SLI_date, '%H:%i') as label ...` then can do away with the foreach